# Solving $x^2y''-xy'+y=x,\;x>0$ with non-constant coefficients using characteristic equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2y''-xy'+y=x,\;x>0$$

Whenever you deal with non-constant coefficients you usually use Laplace transform to solve a given differential equation, at least that's how how I learned it.

How to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you've got this right? I'm pretty sure that the Laplace method can be used on linear differential equations only.

Comment: This is [Euler's differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html)

Comment: @DanielR, this one *is* linear, just not with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you make the substitution $z = \log(x)$ (this is fine as $x > 0$) the differential equation becomes (now using primes to denote differentiation with respect to $z$)

$$y'' - 2y' + y' = e^{z}$$

which is a lot easier to solve. Solving this and substituting $x$ back in will then give the solution (rollover to see)

> $y = Ax + Bx \log(x) + \frac{1}{2} x \log^2(x) $

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitary constants.